# How to preserve full Django Rest Framework's Browsable API functionality on production?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to set `DEBUG = False` in Django, while preserving full **Django Rest Framework's Browsable API functionality**. I'd like to preserve full functionality for whitelisted IP addresses only.

This is how it looks like when `DEBUG = True` is set:

[image: DebugTrue]

- Forms are displayed and working (`Raw data` and `HTML form` tabs)
- `Extra actions` and `OPTIONS` buttons are working
- JSON highlighting is active.

I'd like to preserve this functionality on production (for whitelisted IP addresses only).
As soon as I set DEBUG to False, I lose it.

This is how it looks like when `DEBUG = False` is set:

[image: DebugFalse]

- No forms are displayed
- `Extra actions` and `OPTIONS` buttons are not working
- JSON highlighting isn't active

How to force activate these DRF features while leaving Django in `DEBUG = False` mode? **I'd like to have these features enabled for whitelisted IP addresses. How to achieve this?**

Thank you!